# Why is the return value of this PHP function zero for a long array?

Tags: php, xml

When the `row['error']` is bigger than 35, the value isn't present and the result of the function is 0. Where is the problem?

```
<?php
    if ($row['error'] == "")
    {
        $error = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        $error = $row['error'];
    }

    if ($row['error'] != "")
    {
       if (strlen($error) > 35)
       {
           $error = substr($row['error'],0,32) + "...";
       }
       else
       {
           $error = $row['error'];
       }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
$error = substr($row['error'],0,32) + "...";
```

to:

```
$error = substr($row['error'],0,32) . "...";
```

The concatenate operator in PHP isn't a plus (+)  sign; it's a period (.) sign

Comment: No problem :) I made that mistake so many times when I started PHP.

Comment: And now I'm making the opposite mistake in other languages! Great, short answer, Kranu.

Answer (score 3):

All this code is not necessary. The second condition is redundant, and it doubles the `else` condition from the above. Make it all with just these few lines of code:

```
<?php
    $error = $row['error'];
    if (strlen($error) > 35) {
        $error = substr($row['error'],0,32) . "...";
    }
?>
```

Comment: +1 for optimizing control flow, one of the biggest sources of bugs for beginners

Comment: because in this case, something different is happen. but of course, thank you!

Comment: @Ronny In this code - no, nothing happen. Why don't you explain what you *think* will happen? I don't need your "thank you" nor asking for it. But I can correct my code for that case. Why don't you want to learn something useful?

Answer (score -1):

Because you check:

```
if(strlen($error) > 35) {
}
```